# The debian package with dpkg -i works fine, but the same with "apt install" throws error

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu, shell, apt

Trying to install debian package from server with apt install command.

dpkg: error processing package <pkg_name> (--configure): installed <pkg_name> package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 30 Processing triggers for ufw (0.36-6ubuntu1) ... Errors were encountered while processing: E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I was trying to install the debian from server using "apt install"it throws "dpkg" error. The same is being installed via "dpkg-i" command works fine.

Tried with these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall <pkg_name>
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade 
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: without knowing what pkg_name is ... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ - but why is your debian system referring to `0.36-6ubuntu1`

Comment: I don't know why it is referring to 0.36-6ubuntu1. I'm stuck with that error.

Comment: so ... what's the "pkg_name"

Comment: Generally speaking, don't install ubuntu packages into a debian system or vice versa unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: As of my knowledge, the package is being installed with apt command before i had some changes with it. After some changes in script,the debian package throws the error with apt install command.And the changes are not soo major, minor changes only, I don't think that will throw this kinda error.

Comment: What is the name of the package you're trying to install? What Ubutu release are you running?

Comment: This is our development package in which I'm facing issue. We are hosting in our own server not into the debian server itself.If anyone has come across this error.Kindly help me to sort this. Ubuntu 20.04 server.